# A version of Bertini's Theorem for irreducible varieties.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I propose the following problem.
Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})$ be an irreducible complex projective variety. Is it true that the set of the hyperplanes $H\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ such that $H\cap X$ is irreducible is an open subset of $\mathbb{P}^{n*}$? Is it true that it is non-empty?

Comment: This is also called Bertini's theorem. If $\dim X>1$, the set is non-empty.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it also an open set?
Can you give me a reference?

Comment: Yes, it is open. The place I learned it from is Lang's book on Algebraic Geometry, which is too old fashioned for today's tastes. I would suggest Jounalou's book on Bertini's theorems.

Comment: Do you mean "Introduction to Algebraic Geometry"? What theorem is?
What is the title of the Jonalou's book you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, that is Lang's book and if I remember it, it is called Berini's theorem. Jounalou's book is called  Theoremes de Bertini et applications, Birkhauser.